# Rails 3 - Obtaining the Lates Observer Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's the current flow in my Rails App
1. User uses AJAX and creates a Photo record (stored in DB)
2. Then, the observer catches this and adds a record to the audit log

** That was all without a page refresh. The challenge I have now is that I need to have AJAX return a "news feed" item from the AuditLog created by the observer. It needs to be from the auditlog as I need the auditlog.id for that record.

Ideas? thanks

Comment: How is the Photo model linked to AuditLog model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your models are as follows:

```
class AuditLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :auditable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :audit_logs, :as => :auditable
end
```

The observer callbacks are like regular before and after filters on a model. The callback happens in the same execution block as the save call. So you should be able to access the AuditLog objects using the association on the Photo model.

```
if photo.save
  audit_log = photo.audit_logs(:order => "id DESC").first
  # return the audit_log feed
else
  # error
end
```